# Integer sequence as a non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to pass several arbitrary length integer sequences as non-type parameters to a template class, so the instantiation would look something like this:

```
Foo<Bar, {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7}> foo;
```

Is there a simple way to do this, possibly with C++11?

*** EDIT
Ok, here's a more specific situation:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

void f(vector<int> const & vec1, vector<int> const & vec2) {
    // do something with vec1 and vec2
}

template<MagicalSequenceType & seq1, MagicalSequenceType & seq2>
struct Foo {
    Foo(){
        f(vector<int>(seq1), vector<int>(seq2));
    }
};

main(){
    // I want to be able to do something like this:
    // ideally with syntax this elegant but not necessary
    Foo < {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7} > foo;
}
```

This is a bit on a pseudocode level. I guess **MagicalSequenceType** is what I'm after, be it an actual type or some syntactic template trickery :)

Comment: `{1,2,3,4}` doesn't have a type.

Comment: How do you intend to use the integer sequences?

Comment: There is `std::integer_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` you can create and use

Comment: You can't pass an actual braced list of integers, but using [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) might be possible, depending on your use-case and what problem you're really trying to solve.

Comment: One could potentially represent such a structure with a variadic list of `std::integer_sequence`s, but there's no direct way to specify it. The template must be defined using a generic variadic type, and then specialized to hell and back. This would be a non-starter for me, so: what is the problem you're trying to solve? No, not defining such a template, but the real problem to which you believe the solution is to have a template like this, so that's what you're asking about?

Comment: To clarify a bit. The template class needs to call a plain function with a signature:
`void f(vector<int> const &, vector<int> const &);` which can neatly be called like `f({1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7});`. A call to that function from the template class is always with the same sequences as arguments. So I would like to pass that sequences to a template as its parameters.

Comment: @nj16 That works because `vector` has a *initializer_list* constructor. Also, **specify these important information in your question and not in the comment section**.

Comment: Pass a lambda to the template, that calls `f()` with all the parameters. Highly likely that the compiler ends up inlining it. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Is `Bar` the type of the callable?

Comment: @paolo, no Bar is not really important here. I probably should have left it out from the example.

Comment: @AnoopRana, I'm aware of all of the things you're saying. The gist of the question is **how to pass a sequence of constant as a not-type parameter to a template**. I'll take any syntax or use of other std helper objects as long as they do the job.

Comment: please include a bit more code in the question, for how you want to use the integers sequences. Providing an answer that uses `std::integer_sequence` is simple, but not that useful because it isnt obvious how to use it then

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I added more specific context to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how to use arbitrary length integer sequences as template parameter in `c++11`. It requires a bit of template magic as we can see :P

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

// Crude c++14 integer_sequence
template<int...>
struct ints { };

// Turn an integer sequence into a std::array
template<int... Is>
constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Is)>
ints_to_array(ints<Is...>)
{
    return std::array<int, sizeof...(Is)>{Is...};
}

// Get the n'th sequence from a template parameter pack
template<std::size_t Idx, class First, class... Sequences>
struct get_n
{
    static_assert(Idx < sizeof...(Sequences) + 1, "Idx must be in range"); 
    using type = typename get_n<Idx - 1, Sequences...>::type;
};

template<class First, class... Sequence>
struct get_n<0, First, Sequence...>
{
    using type = First;
};

struct Bar { };

// The class needing multiple integer sequences
template<class T, class... Sequences>
struct Foo
{
    void function_using_second_sequence()
    {
        using sequence = typename get_n<1, Sequences...>::type;
        constexpr auto vals = ints_to_array(sequence());
        for (auto i : vals) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<Bar, ints<1, 2, 3, 4>, ints<5, 6, 7>> foo;
    foo.function_using_second_sequence();
}
```

Try it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/szr3EWTq1)

EDIT: In `c++20` it is much simpler :P

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t Idx, class First, class... Args>
constexpr decltype(auto)
get_n(First&& first, Args&& ...args)
{
    if constexpr (Idx == 0)
        return std::forward<First>(first);
    else
        return get_n<Idx - 1>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class T, auto... Sequences>
struct Foo
{
    void function_using_second_sequence()
    {
        constexpr auto vals = get_n<1>(Sequences...);
        for (auto i : vals) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};

struct Bar { };

int main()
{
    Foo<Bar, std::array{1, 2, 3, 4}, std::array{5, 6, 7}> foo;
    foo.function_using_second_sequence();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mestkon. That's pretty much it. But, wow, there's some serious template voodoo going on here. It'll probably take me a week to fathom it. Btw, can it be done with less brainpower in newer versions of c++? I think I've read somewhere that c++20 supports constexpr vectors, so maybe that could be used.

Comment: Do you really need `to_array()` ? Can't you initialize the array from the `int` sequence in `ints_to_array()`?

Comment: @paolo You are correct. I started from the to_array and built from there :P

Comment: @nj16 Added an example for `c++20`

Comment: Yeah, much neater in c++20

Comment: You might replace `get_n` by std::get<I>(std::tie(Sequences{}...))` or [`std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element).

Answer (score 2):

The standard doesn't allow braced init list `{1,2,3,4}` to be a template argument. This can be seen from [temp.names#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.names):

> ```
> template-argument:
>     constant-expression
>     type-id
>     id-expression
> ```

And since `{1,2,3,4}` is not any of the above three listed constructs, it cannot be used as a template argument.

Additionally note that `{1,2,3,4}` is not an expression and does not have a type.

Comment: I think OP knows this already.

Comment: @paolo I don't think so. I have answered why the syntax used by OP will not work.

Comment: they arent asking specifically for this syntax, but to use an integer sequence and `{1,2,3,4}` is just to illustrate. This is at most half an answer to the question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number So what? Half an answer that is technically correct. There is nothing wrong with the answer. I have answered why the given syntax by OP will not work.

Comment: i didnt say that it is technically wrong. I said it is incomplete

Comment: Right @463035818_is_not_a_number,

I know this syntax won't work, and it's just to illustrate what I want to do. I know how to pass a single constant as a template parameter, but would like to pass an arbitrary length sequence of constants, in fact several of them.

Comment: I didnt reply to your downvote comment. I commented the answer

Comment: fwiw https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Ok, that clears it(that you're weren't replying to my downvote comment) up then.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified answer that assumes you only need 2 integer sequences, instead of a variadic amount of them as in @Mestkon's solution. This supports C++11 since std::integer_sequence was added in C++14. See on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TKfEavr3a)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// std::integer_sequence is since C++14, and the OP requires C++11
template< class T, T... Ints >
class integer_sequence{};

void f(std::vector<int> const & vec1, std::vector<int> const & vec2) {
    for(auto val : vec1) {
        std::cout << val;
    }
    std::cout << " ";
    for(auto val : vec2) {
        std::cout << val;
    }
}

template <class Sequence1, class Sequence2>
struct Foo
{
    Foo() {
        call_f(Sequence1{}, Sequence2{});
    }
    template <class T1, T1 ...Ints1, class T2, T2 ...Ints2>
    void call_f(integer_sequence<T1, Ints1...>, integer_sequence<T2, Ints2...>) {
        f({Ints1...}, {Ints2...});
    }
};

int main() {
    // Prints 1234 567
    Foo<integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3, 4>, integer_sequence<int, 5, 6, 7>> foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @nj16 I'm a little bit salty that OP marked this as the accepted answer since OP specifically asked for *several* sequences, not specifying exactly 2 :P

Comment: Hey @Mestkon, sorry about that. I thought more than one answer can be marked as accepted... shows I'm not very frequent here. Yours is definitely more generalized so it deserves the checkmark ;). Although I'll likely go with something like silversteel's example simply because it's got less triple dots :). Will probably switch the project to c++14 and use std::integer_sequence. Thankyou both for the help.